# Github: API Limit Exceeded (cargo.toml, rust)

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo

The project I'm working on isn't part of a repository (since it is personal) and exceedes the 60/hr limit of authenticated API calls even after the limit is reset. I put my personal access token into VSCode with an environment variable (GITHUB_TOKEN) exported for it as well, and still nothing. Any way to bypass the limit?

My cargo.toml dependencies & features:

````
eventual = "0.1.7"
user-idle = "0.1.1"
chrono = "0.4"
futures = "0.3"
atk = "^0"
glib-sys = "^0"
gobject-sys = "^0"
glib = "^0"
gio = "^0"
gdk = "^0"
gdk-pixbuf = "^0"
gtk = "^0"
once_cell = "^0"
pango = "^0"
pangocairo = "^0"
cairo-rs = { version = "^0", features = ["png"] }

[features]
#default = ["gtk_3_22_30"]
gtk_3_18 = ["gtk/v3_18", "gdk-pixbuf/v2_32", "gdk/v3_18", "gio/v2_46", "glib/v2_46", "pango/v1_38"] #for CI tools
gtk_3_22_30 = ["gtk_3_18", "gtk/v3_22_30", "gdk-pixbuf/v2_36", "gdk/v3_22", "gio/v2_56", "glib/v2_56", "pango/v1_42"] #for CI tools
gtk_3_24 = ["gtk_3_22_30", "gtk/v3_24", "atk/v2_30", "gdk-pixbuf/v2_36_8", "gdk/v3_24", "gio/v2_58", "glib/v2_58"] #for CI tools```
````

Comment: You have code in a project that is not a git repository and still you want to make calls to github.com related to the project....

Comment: This is just because of how rust's cargo system works, is it not? How would a git repository help with that?

Comment: So downloading the dependencies of the rust project gives you a github API call limit?

Comment: Somehow - there are no github calls in my project and it all seems to be coming from the cargo.toml